# Javascript is not submitting on enter key pressed, it just clears the textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
    <form style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px;height:    10%;" id="newmessageForm">
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type your message here"   rows="9" cols="225" id="newmessage" resize="none" style="float: left; opacity: 0.7;"></textarea>
            <input class="btn-login" type="Submit" name="send" style="float: left">
    </form>

<script>
var chatInput = document.getElementById('newmessage');
var chatForm = document.getElementById('newmessageForm');
chatInput.onkeypress = function(e) {
 if (e.charCode == 13) {
   e.preventDefault();
   chatForm.submit();
   }
};
</script>
```

and instead of sending the message on enter key pressed, it just clears the textbox, can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Where is this submitting to? There is no action attribute in the form element. You will need both the method and action attributes in order for the submit to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your form doesn't do anything, it is submitting but the form does not do anything, add an `action=""` and `method=""` for it to show the submit.

Comment: there is another javascript that is handling that... It works to press the button, just not the enter key

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to listen for the enter keypress, instead listen for the form `submit` event and prevent the default action.

```
var chatForm = document.getElementById('newmessageForm');
chatForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```